# Has Rich Burlew ever commented on 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, rpg-pop-culture

I am a big fan of [The Order of the Stick](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0001.html) by Rich Burlew. I even have some of his books not shown on his website, including *Snips, Snails and Dragon Tails*, which contains a story which parodies the mechanics of 4e, and which discusses the very idea of different editions and how it ought to be something we RPGers rally together on rather than argue about.

I'm also a big fan of 5e, with all the changes that it has made to fix problems in previous editions. Though I do admit sometimes I miss the old ways...

Given how big a deal 5e is, and how big a deal Rich is, I find it odd that I have never run across a reference to its existence at all in anything he has written. I've never seen him tweet anything about it, and I've never seen him post about it in his own forum either.

Has he ever mentioned it at all, or said anything about it?

Comment: Also not super sure what to tag it with.

Comment: The problem I see with this question is that I found an example (pretty quickly). That's a valid answer. As soon as someone else finds a different example, that's another, equally valid, answer.

Comment: @Miniman If you found an example, the correct answer to "Has Rich Burlew ever commented on 5e?" would be "yes"...

Comment: @Miniman oh what the hell... was it the tweet about gender-ambiguous elves? I actually found that myself but somehow my brain edited it out and I forgot it immediately upon finding it..... I can't find anything else besides that one though

Comment: @Elmy Yes, but to back up that yes, I would need to give an example. The problem here is that any example is an equally valid answer, and it often happens with questions like this that they develop long lists of "here's another example" answers.

Comment: @Nacht Yeah, that's the one I found with my quick curiosity google. Given that the giantitp forum search is notoriously terrible, I suspect there's probably more out there that could be found with more dedicated searching.

Comment: @Miniman the problem you're describing seems fairly generic - does anyone know if the site have a general policy on questions like this?

Comment: @Vigil [This is the most relevant meta I can find.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5903/15469)

Comment: There's probably a decent research-based question here, but I'm not sure A) if here's the place to ask it, and B) if now's the time to ask it. I think the site can answer a question like *What was Gygax's opinion, if any, on 4e?* because any information like that will be, sadly, unchanging. Burlew, though, is, happily, still creating and could tomorrow deliver a screed against 5e that invalidates any answers that were already posted. Consider instead posing this straight to the *Giant in the Playground* forums.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking whether or not a random personality has commented on an RPG is not relevant.

Comment: @NautArch While I agree on the *has [ever] commented* part, I disagree on the *random personality* part—this isn't Steven Segal, Katy Perry, or another unrelated-to-RPGs dude here. Burlew is influential, both in an RPG sense (e.g. *Order of the Stick* is an RPG touchstone, and he's authored actual gaming material) and in a Web comic sense (it's not *XKCD* or *Penny Arcade*, but I think few would deny *OotS* is successful and important). As Burlew's most popular product is loosely based on an earlier edition, his opinions (and not just their existence) on *D&D* editions seems relevant to me.

Comment: This question needs to go to GiTP forums to be asked and answered.  Rich has commented a number of times why he  has kept the comic based in 3.5.  He discussed why and how the 4e transition was not made (beyond SSaDT) and he's made *at least* one post about 5e not being folded into OoTS.  Suggest the OoTS sub forum, and ask user named Jasdoif for the link.

Comment: @HeyICanChan And we shouldn’t forget [his writings are linked and quoted in the most-highly-rated answer on the site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37105/4563), so he’s not just relevant to RPGs, but to RPG SE as well.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The fact that it could change at any time is a big point indeed. Well, maybe this question contributed in some small way to the definitions of what counts as on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rich Burlew has commented on 5e.

On the 24th of July 2014, Rich Burlew commented in [a tweet](https://twitter.com/richburlew/status/492482317646958592):

> I choose to believe Vaarsuvius was main inspiration for new 5E D&D
>   language on gender-ambiguous elves. Confirm or deny, @aquelajames?

In 2015 [he made a positive observation here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=19164923&postcount=95)

> I'm only just starting to get a handle on Fifth, though, and I do like
>   what I see so far.

Comment: A further data point was posted on the GiTP forum, so I thought I'd edit that in to help your answer.